# Canadian Tax on Loan against FD in NRE account

Tags: taxes, canada, loans

I have Fixed Deposits [Term Deposits] in HDFC NRE account in India. If I take loan against it and transfer loan funds in Canadian dollars to Canada, do I need to pay any taxes in Canada?

Do I need to declare it as income in Canada although it is a loan against Term Deposits sourced outside of Canada?

Comment: Taking out a loan is not income.